# An interesting integral to determine the sign

Tags: integration

I would like to know Whether the   integration

$\int_0^\infty\frac{s^{N_1+N_2}(2s^{N_1+1}-1)}{(1+s^{N_1+1})^4(1+s^{N_2+1})^2}ds$

is positive or negative? where $N_1,N_2$ are positive integers.

I am very grateful if anyone can give some ideas or solutions.

Comment: You probably want to add some context as to why you are interested in this.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  in fact, this integral arises from  the calculation of the vortex nunbers.

Comment: Do you need an answer for all $N_1,N_2$?

Comment: Yes.  Thanks.  Maybe the sign is fixed for all positive integers $N_1, N_2$.

Comment: According to WolframAlpha

N[ integral_0^infinity (s^(3+2) (2 s^(3+1)-1))/((1+s^(3+1))^4 (1+s^(2+1))^2) ds] = -0.000858013

N[ integral_0^infinity (s^(3+4) (2 s^(3+1)-1))/((1+s^(3+1))^4 (1+s^(4+1))^2) ds] = 0.00247042

Answer (score 6):

No, the integral 
$$I(N_1,N_2)=\int_0^\infty\frac{s^{N_1+N_2}(2s^{N_1+1}-1)}{(1+s^{N_1+1})^4(1+s^{N_2+1})^2}ds$$
does not have a fixed sign for positive integers $N_1,N_2$; for example 
$$I(1,1)=-\frac{\pi}{512},\;\;I(1,2)=\frac{11}{8}+\frac{87\pi}{64}-\frac{28\pi}{9\sqrt{3}}\approx 0.00267$$
notice also that $I(2,2)=0$. More generally, $I(N_1,N_2)$ is negative for $N_2\ll N_1$ and positive for $N_2\gg N_1$.

Comment: Hi Carlo Beenakker, Thanks a lot for your answer.  Is there a formula to calculate the integral? How about the case when $N_1$ and $N_2$ are comparable? Does it has a fixed sign? Thanks again.

Comment: It is nice that $I(2,2)=0$. Maybe there are more pairs of parameters when it equals 0? Then we have chance to describe a sign in general situation.

Comment: the sign change happens approximately when $N_1\approx 3N_2$, but only $I(2,2)$ is identically zero.

Comment: This looks interesting. Only $I(2,2)=0$.

Comment: How about the sign for  $I(2,1)$, $I(1,3)$?

Comment: $I(2,1)=\left(\frac{46}{81 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{4}\right) \pi -\frac{1}{4}<0$, $I(1,3)=\frac{1}{128} \left(37-26 \sqrt{2}\right) \pi>0$

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a formula for the integeral in terms of $N_1, N_2$ or for the corresponding indefinite integral?